# how to add whole records of a field in DropDownList from database in asp.net with coding

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, drop-down-menu

Hi i want to add the particular field in dropdownlist by coding
so hows that's possible

Answer (score 1):

not sure from your question, but I think you are looking for...

```
ListItem li = new ListItem();
    li.Text = "yourtext";
    li.Value = "yourvalue";
    li.Selected = true;
    yourDropdown.Items.Add(li);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you mean a new item in drop-down list then use this:

```
ddList.Items.Add("Your New Item");
```

if you are using databinding with datatable having following fields:

```
Name, Age, ID
```

then use this

```
dataTable.Rows.InsertAt(0,new object[]{"[Select]",0,-1});
```